# Post an image to Strapi programmatically with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, strapi

This [Upload documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#upload-files) is all I can find which gives a browser based example using the FormData api.

All it states is that you `POST` to `/uploads` with a `files` parameter of type Buffer/Stream. Here's where I am at so far:

```
fs.readFile(filepath, (err, data) => {
    needle('post','http://localhost:1337/upload', {files: data}, {
        multipart: true,
    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.body);
        if(response.body.data)
            console.log(response.body.data.errors)
    });
});
```

The post is successful but something isn't quite right, the image is registered but missing in the media library with the name of 'files' instead of anything meaningful.

[image]

Example response from the post:

```
[
  {
    id: 170,
    name: 'files',
    alternativeText: null,
    caption: null,
    width: 768,
    height: 1024,
    formats: {
      thumbnail: [Object],
      large: [Object],
      medium: [Object],
      small: [Object]
    },
    hash: 'files_d98a49e7f5',
    ext: '',
    mime: 'application/octet-stream',
    size: 159.62,
    url: '/uploads/files_d98a49e7f5',
    previewUrl: null,
    provider: 'local',
    provider_metadata: null,
    created_at: '2021-06-09T17:12:52.951Z',
    updated_at: '2021-06-09T17:12:52.951Z',
    related: []
  }
]
```

I have also tried using the node module `form-data` to mimic the example provided in the documentation.

```
let form = new FormData();
form.append('files', fs.createReadStream("./test.jpg"))
let data = form //attempt1
let data = {files: form} //attempt2
let data = {files: form.toString()} //attempt3
needle('post','http://localhost:1337/upload', data, {
    multipart: true,
})
```

But this generally returned 400 bad request with the following response:

```
{ id: 'Upload.status.empty', message: 'Files are empty' }
```

Comment: How did you construct the form with form-data? Can you edit your question to include that part.

Comment: @MaximOrlov I have updated the question but also provided an answer after your comment prompted me to read further into the `form-data` module to reach a solution.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the [needle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/needle) http request with the `submit` method provided by the [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) module like so:

```
let form = new FormData();

form.append('files', fs.createReadStream("./testimage.jpg"))
form.append('fileInfo', JSON.stringify({
    alternativeText: 'example'
}));

form.submit('http://localhost:1337/upload', (err,res) => {
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(chunk)) //response file object
      });
})
```